# TDBEdit/TEdit component borders disapear

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a form that correctly displays component borders most of the time.

However when I tab out of the form’s first input field, the borders of all the form’s TDBEdit/TEdit components disappear. The component’s border’s reappear when moused over.

I can reset these at runtime by looping through the form’s components and setting TDBEdit/TEdit borders (BevelInner: bvLowered,   BevelOuter: bvRaised).

Also, this issue appears to have something to do with the Enable runtime themes option in the Project Options. The issue only exists when this option is enabled and regardless of the Windows Theme that is being used.

*CodeGear™ Delphi® 2007 for Win32® R2 Version 11.0.2902.10471*

Answer (score 1):

After some additional research it appears that this is a known issue and occurs predominantly when a user is using the ALT button.

Additional information pertaining to workarounds can be found at:
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=37403

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).